# Получение id элемента одного массива от элемента другого в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть два массива на разных объектах: один массив спрайтов, второй массив аудио. Задача состоит в том, что бы объект с массивом аудио считывал id объекта со спрайтами, и воспроизводил соответствующий звук при нажатии.

часть скрипта объекта с массивом спрайтов:

```
   public class SnapScrolling : MonoBehaviour {
// объявляем количество панелей
    public int panCount;
// Объявляем объект (контент)
    public GameObject panPrefab;
//объявляем массив, в котором будем хранить объекты
    private GameObject[] instPans;
// переменная для поиска id компонента
    public int selectedPanID;
...
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
// найдем объект ближайший к центру экрана
        float nearestPos = float.MaxValue;
        // создаем цикл, который перебирает существующие панельки
        for (int i = 0; i < panCount; i++)
        {
            // берем позицию контента и вычитаем позицию панельки
            float distance = Mathf.Abs(contentRect.anchoredPosition.x - pansPos[i].x); //Mathf.Abs что бы не уйти в минус
            if (distance < nearestPos)
            {
                nearestPos = distance;
                // узнаем id объекта, который ближе к центру
                selectedPanID = i;
            }
}
```

скрипт объекта с аудиоконтентом:

```
public class AnimalVoicesManager : MonoBehaviour {
public AudioClip[] audioClips;

    public static AnimalVoicesManager instance;

    private AudioSource player;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }


    public void playSound(AudioClip clip)
    {
        player.clip = clip;
        player.Play();
    }

    public static AudioClip[] GetClips()
    {
        return instance.audioClips;
    }

    }
```

Comment: "...объект с массивом аудио считывал id объекта со спрайтами, и воспроизводил соответствующий звук..." а какое соответствие между `id`объекта и аудио из массива? По какой характеристике аудио из массива сопрягается с `id`объекта?

Comment: @Bulson явно по названию аудиоклипа

Answer (score 1):

> @Bulson явно по названию аудиоклипа

Значить я могу предположить, что у класса `AudioClip` есть стринговое свойство `Name` и в нем есть значение, кот. можно сравнить с `selectedPanID`.

*Вы улавливаете, что если вы желаете получить нормальный ответ на вопрос, то нужно давать максимум информации для этого, чтоб отвечающий не гадал на кофейной гуще какие у ваших классов свойства и проч.?*

Тогда это можно запрограммировать так, примерно

```
public void PlaySprite(int selectedPanID)
{
    var audio = audioClips.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.Contains($"{selectedPanID}"));
    if (audio != null)
    {
        playSound(audio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну вообще `AudioClip` - это класс Unity, гадать ни на какой гуще не требуется :)

Comment: И единственная правка, там не `Name`, а `name`.

Comment: Тут дело такое... я не пишу под юнити и ничего не знаю о том, что там у нее и как.

Comment: Ну и тем не менее вы указали автору вопроса на неполноту описания. Так что я решил восстановить справедливость.